# Apple iOS Maps URL for Driving Directions

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

Hi everyone I have been banging my head against this for a while and have decided to ask everyone over here at stackoverflow.

Here is an example version of my URL

```
http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=NAS%20WHIDBEY,OAK%20HARBOR,WA,98278&saddr=48.040093999999996,-122.406257
```

Now durring iOS 6 days this automatically converted to driving directions and siri would start talking to you. Now in iOS 7 This does not happen there is a middle ground where its turn by turn directions but it does not talk to you.

How can I force the Apple Maps app to basically open with MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving from a URL not native code.

I know I could pass the Current+Location into the url string but for right now I ask the device what its location is and then pass it along.

Any help would be appreciated.